# How to access special properties of ngRepeat in md-virtual-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am unable to access [special](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) properties of ngRepeat in md-virtual-repeat. I would like access $last property for the md-divider. However this always returns null.

Comment: what are you attempting to do with `$last`? (there is perhaps a better way to do this without needing to access it)

Comment: may be md-on-demand attribute with getLength() function can help you I am not yet sure but you can check that as It will give you length which is basically your $last

Answer (score 1):

As stated at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat,

> Virtual repeat is a limited substitute for `ng-repeat`

actually it supports only `$index`.

In case when `md-on-demand` directive is used you can use `getLength()` function as @Ashish already said:

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
  <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems" 
       md-on-demand 
       class="repeated-item" 
       flex>
    {{item}}
    <md-divider ng-if="$index !== ctrl.dynamicItems.getLength() - 1"></md-divider>
  </div>

</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

if you do not want to use `md-on-demand` directive, then you can use `items.length`:

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container2">
  <div md-virtual-repeat="i in ctrl.items" class="repeated-item" flex>
    Hello {{i}}!
    <md-divider ng-if="$index !== (ctrl.items.length - 1)"></md-divider>
  </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

here is modified official codepan: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRaoJK